# pandas function to keep only words and phrases from a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df like this...

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic 1998','2001 Toyota Corolla','99 Ford','2011 Audi']}
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand'])
```

and a list like this..

```
mylist = ['Honda Civic','Ford','Audi']
```

I am trying extract only the elements from the list into a new column with...

```
df['words from list'] = df['Brand'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if i in (mylist)]))
```

I am getting..

```
Brand                  words from list
Honda Civic 1998    
2001 Toyota Corolla 
99 Ford                Ford
2011 Audi              Audi
```

How to I get the extract to include the elements from the list with spaces without parsing out the list further? Why isn't the space in the list recognized?

expected outcome is...

```
Brand                  words from list
Honda Civic 1998       Honda Civic
2001 Toyota Corolla 
99 Ford                Ford
2011 Audi              Audi
```

Comment: When you use x.split() you are pulling individual words from your brand column, e.g. 'Honda' then 'Civic' then '1998'. In your list however, 'Honda Civic' is passed as a single item. In essence then you are checking if 'Honda' = 'Honda Civic'. The solution below should cover you or else use a regex or rewrite your list comprehension to query the list not x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pandas series.str.extract should do:

```
df['words_from_list'] = df['Brand'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(mylist)+')',expand=False)

print(df)

                 Brand words_from_list
0     Honda Civic 1998     Honda Civic
1  2001 Toyota Corolla             NaN
2              99 Ford            Ford
3            2011 Audi            Audi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand'])
>>> df
                 Brand
0     Honda Civic 1998
1  2001 Toyota Corolla
2              99 Ford
3            2011 Audi
>>> mylist = ['Honda Civic','Ford','Audi']
>>> df['words from list'] = df['Brand'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(mylist)+')')
>>> df
                 Brand words from list
0     Honda Civic 1998     Honda Civic
1  2001 Toyota Corolla             NaN
2              99 Ford            Ford
3            2011 Audi            Audi
>>>
```